# How to match child documents with parents when using a subquery?

Tags: solr

I want to use a subquery in Solar, but my child documents are retrieved with unrelated parents.

Example of a model:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "parent_title": "stack overflow question 1",
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "child_body": "body of title 1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "parent_title": "stack overflow question 2",
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "child_body": "body of title 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm using the following query:

```
q= parent_title:stack
fl= *, subquery:[subquery]&subquery.q=child_body:title
```

Results:

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "parent_title":["stack overflow question 1"],
    "subquery":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
        {
          "id":"1",
          "child_body":["body of title 1"]
        },
        {
          "id":"2",
          "child_body":["body of title 2"]            
        }]
    }
},
{
    "id":"2",
    "parent_title":["stack overflow question 2"],
    "subquery":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
        {
          "id":"1",
          "child_body":["body of title 1"]        
        },
        {
          "id":"2",
          "child_body":["body of title 2"],
        }]
    }
}
```

**Problem**: I don't want to retrieve the child "title 2" under parent "question 1". So, how do I match my subquery childs to their corresponding parents?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your model to include a `parent_id` and filter by the `$row.id`.

#### Model:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "parent_title": "stack overflow question 1",
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "child_body": "body of title 1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "parent_title": "stack overflow question 2",
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "child_body": "body of title 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Query:

```
q= parent_title:stack
fl= *, subquery:[subquery]&subquery.q=child_body:title&subquery.fq={!terms f=parent_id v=$row.id}
```

#### Results:

```json
[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "parent_title":["stack overflow question 1"],
        "subquery":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
            {
              "id":"1",
              "parent_id":[1],
              "child_body":["body of title 1"],
              "$row.id":1000
            }
        ]}
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "parent_title":["stack overflow question 2"],
        "subquery":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
            {
              "id":"2",
              "parent_id":[2],
              "child_body":["body of title 2"],
              "$row.id":2000
            }
        ]}
    }
]
```